# Ruby CSV - get current line/row number

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to work out how to get the current line/row number from Ruby CSV. This is my code:

```
options = {:encoding => 'UTF-8', :skip_blanks => true}
CSV.foreach("data.csv", options, ) do |row, i|
   puts i
end
```

But this doesn't seem to work as expected. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

*Because of changes in CSV in current Rubies, we need to make some changes. See farther down in the answer for the original solution with Ruby prior to 2.6. and the use of `with_index` which continues to work regardless of the version.*

*For 2.6+ this'll work:*

```
require 'csv'

puts RUBY_VERSION

csv_file = CSV.open('test.csv')
csv_file.each do |csv_row|
  puts '%i %s' % [csv_file.lineno, csv_row]
end
csv_file.close
```

If I read:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

The code results in this output:

```
2.6.3
1 ["Year", "Make", "Model", "Description", "Price"]
2 ["1997", "Ford", "E350", "ac, abs, moon", "3000.00"]
3 ["1999", "Chevy", "Venture \"Extended Edition\"", "", "4900.00"]
4 ["1999", "Chevy", "Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"", "", "5000.00"]
5 ["1996", "Jeep", "Grand Cherokee", "MUST SELL!\\nair, moon roof, loaded", "4799.00"]
```

The change is because we have to get access to the current file handle. Previously we could use the global `$.`, which always had a possibility of failure because globals can get stomped on by other sections of called code. If we have the handle of the file being opened, then we can use `lineno` without that concern.

---

### `$.`

*Ruby prior to 2.6 would let us do this:*

Ruby has a [magic variable `$.`](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/English/rdoc/index.html) which is the line number of the current file being read:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |csv|
  puts $.
end
```

with the code above, I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

### `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`

`$.` is used all the time in Perl. In Ruby, it's recommended we use it the following way to avoid the "magical" side of it:

```
require 'english'

puts $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER
```

---

If it's necessary to deal with embedded line-ends in fields, it's easily handled by a minor modification. Assuming a CSV file "test.csv" which contains a line with an embedded new-line:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","",5000.00
```

---

### `with_index`

Using Enumerator's [`with_index(1)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) makes it easy to keep track of the number of times CSV yields to the block, effectively simulating using `$.` but honoring CSV's work when reading the extra lines necessary to deal with the line-ends:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('test.csv', headers: true).with_index(1) do |row, ln|
  puts '%-3d %-5s %-26s %s' % [ln, *row.values_at('Make', 'Model', 'Description')]
end
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
$ ruby test.rb
1   Ford  E350                       ac, abs, moon
2   Chevy Venture "Extended Edition"
3   Jeep  Grand Cherokee             MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded
4   Chevy Venture "Extended Edition, Very Large"
```

Comment: this had unexpected results in rspec

Comment: This wasn't written to work in rspec. It works in regular Ruby.

Comment: Any idea what happens when you use the `headers: true` option. Is the first line still `1` or is it `2`?

Comment: FYI, if you use the `headers: true` option, the first *row* returns `2`.

Comment: If you use `headers: true` it returns `2` because it's reading the second row. Why wouldn't it? The first row was read by CSV as a header. Think about it.

Comment: Rails is Ruby so it works, so you are doing something wrong. If it's important to your code I'd suggest asking a question.

Comment: Don't use this. Use each_with_index as described by Josh Voigts below. Requiring "english" does not make it less magic, it just gives a name to it.

Comment: Rather than say "don't use this", explain why in a separate answer. Help educate.

Comment: The problem with using `$.` is it's the **line number**, which does not always reflect the **row number** since a cell can contain multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but it's an easy work-around. See the code.

Comment: `$.` and `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` worked for us with Ruby 2.5.0 but not after upgrading to 2.6.2, it just keeps returning 1. Had to use `.with_index` instead.

Comment: Yes, `$.` and `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` are globals. See the added information in the answer. `with_index` works, or using `FILE.lineno`. It's always possible that embedded carriage returns in the CSV file or certain options to CSV's reading will confuse tracking line numbers, at which point it becomes an exercise for the developer to figure out because Ruby won't be able to read their mind.

Answer (score 36):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
options = {:encoding => 'UTF-8', :skip_blanks => true}

CSV.foreach("data.csv", options).with_index do |row, i|
   puts i
end
```

Comment: Yes, this works and is clean. But it requires reading the whole CVS content into RAM at once. This is what `read` does.

Comment: According to the CSV documentation, `read` actually _slurps_ the data in. [http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read)

Comment: You want to say, that "slurp" somehow means lazy reading? I doub't that. The result of the `read` is an `Array` and as far as I know there is no way to have deferred array building in Ruby.

Comment: Indeed to *slurp* usually means *to read all at once* on this context.

Comment: Instead of `each_with_index`, you should use `with_index`. `each_with_index` would require Ruby to load the entire file.

Comment: Updated example to use `with_index` instead.

Answer (score 8):

### Ruby 2.6+

#### Without Headers

```
CSV.foreach( "data.csv", encoding: "UTF-8" ).with_index do |row, row_number|
  puts row_number
end
```

#### With Headers

```
CSV.foreach( "data.csv", encoding: "UTF-8", headers: true ).with_index( 2 ) do |row, row_number|
  puts row_number # Starts at row 2, which is the first row after the header row.
end
```

*In Ruby 2.6, `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` no longer gives you the current line number. What's worse is that it's returning values of `2` and `1`. I'm not sure what that is supposed to represent but it's certainly not the row number. Since it doesn't raise an exception, it can really bite you if you're not checking that value. **I highly recommend you replace all occurrences of `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` in your code to avoid this gotcha.***

Answer (score 6):

Not a clean but a simple solution

```
options = {:encoding => 'UTF-8', :skip_blanks => true}
i = 0
CSV.foreach("data.csv", options) do | row |
  puts i
  i += 1
end
```

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to get the row number, not the line number **but**, you should offset `i` by 1 if `:headers => true`.

Comment: Using `with_index` would be a cleaner, more Ruby-like, solution.