# How to select specific rows in CSV files?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

For example, maybe I want to start from the 5th row:

```
csv_text = File.read(file)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv[20..-1].each do |row|

end
```

Is it possible to write something like `csv[5..-1]`, from the 5th to the last row?

Comment: That's not a duplicate question. This question is about how to get a RANGE of lines - not a line NUMBER. That's a different thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `CSV.foreach` method to iterate over the CSV and the [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) method to count the rows you read and skip rows you don't want to process. For example:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(file, headers: true).with_index(1) do |row, rowno|   
  next if rowno < 5 # skips first four rows
  # process the row
end
```

In Ruby 1.9.3 this wouldn't work since `foreach` doesen't return an `Enumerator` if no block is given. The code can be modified like this:

```
CSV.to_enum(:foreach, file, headers: true).with_index(1) do |row, rowno|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I get a `IOError: closed stream` with the `with_index` method.

Comment: Are you using Ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: Yes...So this is a problem with ruby version?

Comment: Finally, I find this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407035/ruby-csv-get-current-line-row-number`. So I can use `$.` instead.